# Delphi Forms won't resize on remote access

Tags: forms, delphi, resize

I'm working from home today. I'm accessing my work machine from my home computer and all forms on my BDS 2006 won't resize beyond 1378x780. Auto-Size is disabled, I've tried changing size on dfm text, on Object Inspector, I've reppaired the installation. It's not related to a specific project, this happens in all forms.

How can I repair this?

Comment: It's most likely a limitation on screen size from your remote connection settings. There's nothing we can do from here to help with that, unfortunately.

Comment: I use RDP all the time. I've never seen such an issue. But if this is really true, then what Ken said is probably the case.

Comment: Correct, if your using RDP, edit the connection and increase the screen size on the Display tab.

Comment: Older Delphi VCL have some issues when used over RDP, e.g. in Delphi 2007 sometimes the TForm.Monitor property is NIL which results in an Access Violation in all methods that access it. I haven't seen this particular problem though.

Comment: Just tried to set a form width to 5000 and it got reset back to 3860. Using BDS 2006 with without a VM so there must be a limit set by Delphi.